# Retrieving passwords from AWS SSM Parameter store for Dropwizard

Tags: amazon-web-services, dropwizard, aws-ssm

I'm new to Dropwizard and looking to retrieve secrets from AWS SSM Parameter store when the application bootstraps. I have two questions on how to do this:

1. Where should I be doing this? In the initialize method?
2. Once I make a call to AWS SSM Parameter Store where is the best location to place it? I had a quick look inside the Bootstrap class but it's not obvious to me where I should place things like secrets etc to be retrieved later.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want by setting up a `ConfigurationSourceProvider` where you substitute configuration settings with the value of Parameter Store variables.

```
@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<MyConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    ParameterStoreSourceProvider parameterStoreSourceProvider =
            new ParameterStoreSourceProvider(bootstrap.getConfigurationSourceProvider());
    bootstrap.setConfigurationSourceProvider(parameterStoreSourceProvider);
}
```

Implement a `ConfigurationSourceProvider` that takes over configuration input stream from the delegate to substitute values.

```
public class ParameterStoreSourceProvider implements ConfigurationSourceProvider {
    private final ConfigurationSourceProvider delegate;
    private final StringSubstitutor substitutor;

    public ParameterStoreSourceProvider(ConfigurationSourceProvider delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.substitutor = new StringSubstitutor(new ParameterStoreLookup());
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream open(String path) throws IOException {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(delegate.open(path))) {
            String config = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
            String substituted = substitutor.replace(config);
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(substituted.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }
    }
}
```

Implement your `ParameterStoreLookup` where you let `StringSubstitutor` to use it as variable resolver.

```
public class ParameterStoreLookup implements StringLookup {
    @Override
    public String lookup(String s) {
        // Lookup the value from Parameter Store and return.
        return null;
    }
}
```

After above steps, you can define a variable in your configuration file shown as below:

```
database:
    driverClass : org.postgresql.Driver
    url: ${DB_URL}
    user: ${DB_USER}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
logging:
    level: INFO
    appenders:
        - type: console
```

Please see [StringSubstitutor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html) for more information on defining variables. Make sure to add [commons-text](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text) to your dependencies.